# How to accept the 2d array being returned

Tags: java, arrays

In my below code, I'm checking whether the entered rows and columns are equal and then accepting the array and proceeding to calculate the sum of the diagonal elements. I understand that I can take only one variable for rows and columns but this is what our assignment says.

```
import java.util.*;

class main
{
int[][] acceptarray(int a[][])   //Accepting the 2d array
{
    Scanner xd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter the elements of array : ");

    for( int i =0; i <a.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<a[0].length; j++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter element "+(i)+","+(j));
        a[i][j] = xd.nextInt();
        }
    }
    xd.close();
    return(a);
}

boolean check(int b[][])  //checking whether rows and colums are equal or not
{
    if(b.length==b[0].length)
    {return(true);}

    else
    return(false);

}

int sum(int c[][])  // Sum of the the diagonal of the matrix
{   int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=c.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=c[0].length;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
            
            sum =sum+c[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return(sum);
}}

class dsum
{
public static void main(String Args[])
{
    
    Scanner xd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of Rows");
    int m = xd.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of Columns");
    int n = xd.nextInt();
    xd.close();
    int a[][] = new int [m][n];

    main s = new main();
    boolean p = s.check(a);
    
    if(p)
    {   
        System.out.print("It is a Square Matrix:\n\n");
        s.acceptarray(a);
        int b[][] =s.acceptarray();    //line with the error message
        s.sum(b);
        
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("It's not a square matrix");
        System.exit(0);
    }   

}
}
```

> The error message is:

```
                b =s.acceptarray();
                    ^
  required: int[][]
  found: no argument
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

For the record, I'm a newbie so I'm not aware of the all the concepts.
So, Can someone please help  me out on how to accept this 2d array that is being returned by the *acceptarray* function. It'll help me understand the only concept I'm not able to understand since a week.

Peace.

Comment: You don't need `b`. Just call `s.sum(a);`

Comment: you are not passing any variable to `acceptarray` method. you have to pass arguments according to the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You never declared a method `acceptarray` that doesn't take an argument. Try `int b[][] =s.acceptarray(a);`